# What is the best way to make another app active in Cocoa?

Tags: applescript, switch-statement, nsapplication

I have an app that generates key commands in another app. I used to do it in Applescript studio but I have rewritten in Obj-C.  Now I can't figure out how to make the other active in the foreground so I can start generating key commands.

Currently I am just running an Applescript call:

```
key = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"tell application \"Pro Tools\" to activate"];
[key executeAndReturnError:nil] ;
```

The PID for Protools is 14925.  I was thinking I could use NSApplications, but I don't think that is the right call.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
[[NSRunningApplication runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier:PID] activateWithOptions:NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps];
```